# ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: error with Rails 7, Heroku and PostGreSQL14

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

I'm building a blog site. It's built on Rails 7 and I've switched from SQlite3 to PostgreSQL so that my app can run on Heroku. When I try to launch my app on Heroku I get the generic error message: "We're sorry, but something went wrong."

After digging through the Heroku logs, this is what I get:

```
 ›   Warning: heroku update available from 8.0.5 to 8.0.6.
2023-04-26T07:04:58.074841+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p ${PORT:-5000} -e production`
2023-04-26T07:05:00.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2023-04-26T07:05:00.172930+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2023-04-26T07:05:00.172963+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 7.0.4.3 application starting in production
2023-04-26T07:05:00.172963+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
2023-04-26T07:05:01.116758+00:00 app[web.1]: Puma starting in single mode...
2023-04-26T07:05:01.116781+00:00 app[web.1]: * Puma version: 5.6.5 (ruby 3.1.2-p20) ("Birdie's Version")
2023-04-26T07:05:01.116783+00:00 app[web.1]: *  Min threads: 5
2023-04-26T07:05:01.116783+00:00 app[web.1]: *  Max threads: 5
2023-04-26T07:05:01.116783+00:00 app[web.1]: *  Environment: production
2023-04-26T07:05:01.116783+00:00 app[web.1]: *          PID: 2
2023-04-26T07:05:01.117024+00:00 app[web.1]: * Listening on http://0.0.0.0:18356
2023-04-26T07:05:01.120649+00:00 app[web.1]: Use Ctrl-C to stop
2023-04-26T07:05:01.294531+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2023-04-26T07:05:19.244326+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `rails db:create` by user myname@gmail.com
2023-04-26T07:05:22.101241+00:00 heroku[run.9744]: Awaiting client
2023-04-26T07:05:22.219821+00:00 heroku[run.9744]: State changed from starting to up
2023-04-26T07:05:22.851411+00:00 heroku[run.9744]: Starting process with command `rails db:create`
2023-04-26T07:05:28.268798+00:00 heroku[run.9744]: Process exited with status 1
2023-04-26T07:05:28.298884+00:00 heroku[run.9744]: State changed from up to complete
2023-04-26T10:28:47.730233+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2023-04-26T10:28:47.730142 #2]  INFO -- : [09ef40c9-e747-4ef7-b312-599796c6386b] Started GET "/" for 1.145.159.41 at 2023-04-26 10:28:47 +0000
2023-04-26T10:28:47.732335+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2023-04-26T10:28:47.732265 #2]  INFO -- : [09ef40c9-e747-4ef7-b312-599796c6386b] Processing by BlogPostsController#index as HTML
2023-04-26T10:28:47.734099+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2023-04-26T10:28:47.734044 #2]  INFO -- : [09ef40c9-e747-4ef7-b312-599796c6386b] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms (Allocations: 1520)
2023-04-26T10:28:47.734912+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=myname-blog.herokuapp.com request_id=09ef40c9-e747-4ef7-b312-599796c6386b fwd="1.145.159.41" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=12ms status=500 bytes=1827 protocol=https
2023-04-26T10:28:47.734961+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2023-04-26T10:28:47.734926 #2] FATAL -- : [09ef40c9-e747-4ef7-b312-599796c6386b]
2023-04-26T10:28:47.734963+00:00 app[web.1]: [09ef40c9-e747-4ef7-b312-599796c6386b] ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished (connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
2023-04-26T10:28:47.734964+00:00 app[web.1]: Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?
2023-04-26T10:28:47.734965+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2023-04-26T10:28:47.734966+00:00 app[web.1]: [09ef40c9-e747-4ef7-b312-599796c6386b]
2023-04-26T10:28:47.734966+00:00 app[web.1]: [09ef40c9-e747-4ef7-b312-599796c6386b] app/controllers/blog_posts_controller.rb:7:in `index'
2023-04-26T10:28:48.114685+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=myname-blog.herokuapp.com request_id=17872943-0522-411a-8d92-618d73c906ad fwd="1.145.159.41" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=15553 protocol=https
2023-04-26T10:33:23.625133+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `rails db:create` by user myname@gmail.com
2023-04-26T10:33:27.181577+00:00 heroku[run.2681]: Awaiting client
2023-04-26T10:33:27.198319+00:00 heroku[run.2681]: Starting process with command `rails db:create`
2023-04-26T10:33:27.248207+00:00 heroku[run.2681]: State changed from starting to up
2023-04-26T10:33:32.007028+00:00 heroku[run.2681]: Process exited with status 1
2023-04-26T10:33:32.048189+00:00 heroku[run.2681]: State changed from up to complete
2023-04-26T10:49:17.463329+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2023-04-26T10:49:17.463264 #2]  INFO -- : [4be180a1-c5d4-4060-a0a7-5545c78fe28a] Started GET "/" for 1.145.159.41 at 2023-04-26 10:49:17 +0000
2023-04-26T10:49:17.464018+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2023-04-26T10:49:17.463954 #2]  INFO -- : [4be180a1-c5d4-4060-a0a7-5545c78fe28a] Processing by BlogPostsController#index as HTML
2023-04-26T10:49:17.464717+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2023-04-26T10:49:17.464686 #2]  INFO -- : [4be180a1-c5d4-4060-a0a7-5545c78fe28a] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms (Allocations: 865)
2023-04-26T10:49:17.465178+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2023-04-26T10:49:17.465153 #2] FATAL -- : [4be180a1-c5d4-4060-a0a7-5545c78fe28a]
2023-04-26T10:49:17.465179+00:00 app[web.1]: [4be180a1-c5d4-4060-a0a7-5545c78fe28a] ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished (connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
2023-04-26T10:49:17.465180+00:00 app[web.1]: Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?
2023-04-26T10:49:17.465181+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2023-04-26T10:49:17.465181+00:00 app[web.1]: [4be180a1-c5d4-4060-a0a7-5545c78fe28a]
2023-04-26T10:49:17.465182+00:00 app[web.1]: [4be180a1-c5d4-4060-a0a7-5545c78fe28a] app/controllers/blog_posts_controller.rb:7:in `index'
2023-04-26T10:49:17.465388+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=myname-blog.herokuapp.com request_id=4be180a1-c5d4-4060-a0a7-5545c78fe28a fwd="1.145.159.41" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=500 bytes=1827 protocol=https
2023-04-26T10:49:17.831119+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=myname-blog.herokuapp.com request_id=20173cc4-605b-423a-bb21-968e0b7d33ec fwd="1.145.159.41" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=15553 protocol=https
2023-04-27T07:51:01.874384+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Cycling
2023-04-27T07:51:01.890379+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2023-04-27T07:51:02.504938+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2023-04-27T07:51:02.629392+00:00 app[web.1]: - Gracefully stopping, waiting for requests to finish
2023-04-27T07:51:02.667731+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2023-04-27T07:51:02.858102+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2023-04-27T07:51:04.649358+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p ${PORT:-5000} -e production`
2023-04-27T07:51:06.214574+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2023-04-27T07:51:06.214598+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 7.0.4.3 application starting in production
2023-04-27T07:51:06.214598+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
2023-04-27T07:51:07.047605+00:00 app[web.1]: Puma starting in single mode...
2023-04-27T07:51:07.047633+00:00 app[web.1]: * Puma version: 5.6.5 (ruby 3.1.2-p20) ("Birdie's Version")
2023-04-27T07:51:07.047636+00:00 app[web.1]: *  Min threads: 5
2023-04-27T07:51:07.047637+00:00 app[web.1]: *  Max threads: 5
2023-04-27T07:51:07.047637+00:00 app[web.1]: *  Environment: production
2023-04-27T07:51:07.047637+00:00 app[web.1]: *          PID: 2
2023-04-27T07:51:07.047822+00:00 app[web.1]: * Listening on http://0.0.0.0:48574
2023-04-27T07:51:07.051067+00:00 app[web.1]: Use Ctrl-C to stop
2023-04-27T07:51:07.357981+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2023-04-27T09:10:30.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user myname@gmail.com
2023-04-27T09:10:59.411699+00:00 app[api]: Release v10 created by user myname@gmail.com
2023-04-27T09:10:59.411699+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 903d73f0 by user myname@gmail.com
2023-04-27T09:10:59.786911+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2023-04-27T09:10:59.799563+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2023-04-27T09:11:00.328611+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2023-04-27T09:11:00.368466+00:00 app[web.1]: - Gracefully stopping, waiting for requests to finish
2023-04-27T09:11:00.369091+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2023-04-27T09:11:00.529935+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2023-04-27T09:11:02.891039+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p ${PORT:-5000} -e production`
2023-04-27T09:11:04.415587+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2023-04-27T09:11:04.415609+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 7.0.4.3 application starting in production
2023-04-27T09:11:04.415609+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
2023-04-27T09:11:05.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2023-04-27T09:11:05.254030+00:00 app[web.1]: Puma starting in single mode...
2023-04-27T09:11:05.254055+00:00 app[web.1]: * Puma version: 5.6.5 (ruby 3.1.2-p20) ("Birdie's Version")
2023-04-27T09:11:05.254058+00:00 app[web.1]: *  Min threads: 5
2023-04-27T09:11:05.254059+00:00 app[web.1]: *  Max threads: 5
2023-04-27T09:11:05.254059+00:00 app[web.1]: *  Environment: production
2023-04-27T09:11:05.254059+00:00 app[web.1]: *          PID: 2
2023-04-27T09:11:05.254197+00:00 app[web.1]: * Listening on http://0.0.0.0:35610
2023-04-27T09:11:05.257347+00:00 app[web.1]: Use Ctrl-C to stop
2023-04-27T09:11:05.807424+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2023-04-27T09:11:07.323669+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2023-04-27T09:11:07.323602 #2]  INFO -- : [ceeee860-5a73-4142-a3fe-c84bf7284f48] Started GET "/" for 1.145.159.41 at 2023-04-27 09:11:07 +0000
2023-04-27T09:11:07.324817+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2023-04-27T09:11:07.324777 #2]  INFO -- : [ceeee860-5a73-4142-a3fe-c84bf7284f48] Processing by BlogPostsController#index as HTML
2023-04-27T09:11:07.326433+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2023-04-27T09:11:07.326404 #2]  INFO -- : [ceeee860-5a73-4142-a3fe-c84bf7284f48] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms (Allocations: 1813)
2023-04-27T09:11:07.326779+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2023-04-27T09:11:07.326759 #2] FATAL -- : [ceeee860-5a73-4142-a3fe-c84bf7284f48]
2023-04-27T09:11:07.326779+00:00 app[web.1]: [ceeee860-5a73-4142-a3fe-c84bf7284f48] ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished (connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 5432 failed: Connection refused
2023-04-27T09:11:07.326782+00:00 app[web.1]: Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
2023-04-27T09:11:07.326782+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2023-04-27T09:11:07.326783+00:00 app[web.1]: [ceeee860-5a73-4142-a3fe-c84bf7284f48]
2023-04-27T09:11:07.326783+00:00 app[web.1]: [ceeee860-5a73-4142-a3fe-c84bf7284f48] app/controllers/blog_posts_controller.rb:7:in `index'
2023-04-27T09:11:07.328061+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=myname-blog.herokuapp.com request_id=ceeee860-5a73-4142-a3fe-c84bf7284f48 fwd="1.145.159.41" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=8ms status=500 bytes=1827 protocol=https
```

And after running command 'rails db:migrate' I run into this error:

```
PG::Coder.new(hash) is deprecated. Please use keyword arguments instead! Called from /Users/my_username/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.4.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:980:in `new'
```

Things I've done so far:
Restarted the server
Uninstalled postgres then reinstalled it with brew (running PostgreSQL 14.7 (Homebrew))
Update the pg gem to pg 1.5.2

I'm not sure if there's an error with the postgres install that's causing this, or something else.

Comment: Did you check that DATABASE_URL environment variable is correctly setup ?

Comment: when I checked the database_url in rails console, it returned 'nil'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating `pg` gem: `bundle update pg`

I was getting the same warning after upgrading to Ruby 3.2.2, and it got fixed after updating `pg` gem.

Comment: This solved it with another tweak to the yaml file. Thanks!

Comment: pg v1.5.3 made some changes to suppress these warnings generally unless the runtime is configured to show deprecation warnings: https://github.com/ged/ruby-pg/blob/master/History.md#v153-2023-04-28-lars-kanis-larsgreiz-reinsdorfde

Answer (score 1):

PG::Coder.new(hash) is not the problem you should looking for,
Have the same, rspec pass all model tests.
Activerecord version the same activerecord-7.0.4.3

Comment: I'm fairly new to Rails, so I'm not sure what you mean by this, "you should looking for Have the same," can you explain further

Comment: sorry for bad english, I mean it's not the problem, that cause your 500 error

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).